# Font monospace Android 2.3

Tags: android, css, font-face, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-2.2-froyo

I have a problem with a mobile website on Android Gingerbread and versions prior to this. Fonts monospace do not exactly behave as monospaces should: different characters have different widths.

This is how it looks on a Gingerbread default web browser (I also tested on Dolphin and Opera mini):

[image: Gingerbread screenshot]

This is how it looks on a ICS default web browser:

[image: ICS screenshot]

I used the Cultive Mono downloaded from the web.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

CSS:

```
#my_id span{font:12px  'Cutive Mono', serif; line-height:1.6}
```

I also tried the default monospace font from the OS:

```
#my_id span{font:12px  monospace; line-height:1.6}
```

Does anybody know how can this issue be solved? I really need a monospace working on my mobile website.

Thanks in advance.

### edit

This would be an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/dE94s/9/

Comment: Unless you take the time to explain **precisely** what you mean by "a little differences that mess up the exactly view that I need to show" -- possibly including screenshots -- it will be very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare! See my edited version =]

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems that even that I set monospace font it isn't monospace. You can check my testing page that I've work on: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/android.html if you take a look the space (prompt) is very narrow, it should be the same width as letters.

Comment: @jcubic check out my answer, I think using the correct font family css parameter will fix the issue on your site

Comment: Huh, I came here with the exact same issue, for Guitar Diagrams! Have you seen this style of guitar ascii: ```
E┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐ 
B├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤ 
G├───┼───┼b7─┼───┼───┤ 
D├───┼─3─┼───┼───┼───┤ 
A├───┼───┼─1─┼───┼───┤ 
E└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘ 
 ``` (Naturally, it's all messed up here in the comments...)

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix for my case, it's seems that Andorid don't render fonts if one is missing.

this don't work:

```
font-family: FreeMono, Courier, monospace;
```

but work if I use:

```
font-family: FreeMono, Courier, monospace;
font-family: monospace;
```

In this code probably second rule overwrite the first one.

Just another weird thing with browsers, if anybody explain this or give more details, I'll give him a bounty.

Comment: Strange, it seems that 2.3 android does not fallback correctly to other font families when one fails. I'll suggest that you embed your font with eg. google fonts if you want a custom font or otherwise just use `monospace` and let the system decide if you want mobile compatibility.

Comment: @for3st I didn't decide yet to use Andorid hack from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/ or just use `font-family: monospace;` maybe I use just monospace.

Answer (score 0):

This sample works fine on my 2.3.3 (SDK Lvl 10) android emulator:

http://jsfiddle.net/dE94s/3/

CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono);

.cutive_block {
    font-family: 'Cutive Mono', Courier, monospace;
}

.monospace_block {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    Some default text
</div>    
<div class="cutive_block">
    Some text in cutive mono
</div>
<div class="cutive_block">
And a second line that shows it's monospace
</div>

<div class="monospace_block">
    Some text in default monospace
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see in the second and third line which uses your custom font is monospaced.

So I guess just use `font-family` css attribute with correct fallback font types:

```
font-family: 'Cutive Mono', Courier, monospace;
```

as suggested here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: It work in jsFiddle on a Phone but not on my site, I've used: `.terminal, .cmd { font-family: FreeMono, Courier, monospace;` Here is my css http://terminal.jcubic.pl/css/jquery.terminal.css

Answer (score 0):

I realize it may be late, but I was having trouble with Google Fonts and found a workaround: [Mononoki](https://madmalik.github.io/mononoki/) and Adobe's [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro) have all characters, including box drawing.

The problem with Google is that [some gliphs are missing](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts/issues/617).